# Handle 2nd level child window in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an application which contains multiple popups. I click on a button and a popup window opens(say `title="Child1"`). I am able to work on this popup window. When i click on a button in the child1 window, a third popup opens(say `grandchild1`). So it is something like:

```
MainWindow<----Child1<---Grandchild1
```

Selenium is not able to recognize the grandchild window.

```
win=driver.getWindowHandles().toArray();
```

this code also shows only 2 windows.

```
selenium.selectWindow("Grandchild1");
```

This code also throws an error. Any help on this?

Comment: Could you please paste the error thrown in question?

Answer (score 0):

Do your operations with below flow to handle multiple windows in WebDriver.

```
String mainWindowHanhle=driver.getWindowHandle();

//Do/Click something to open child window

Set<String> childParentHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();

childParentHandles.remove(mainWindowHanhle);   //removing main window handle from Set

driver.switchTo().window((String) childParentHandles.toArray()[0]); //switching the control to child window

//Do/Click something in Child window to open grand_child window

Set<String> grandChild_Child_ParentHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();

grandChild_Child_ParentHandles.remove(mainWindowHanhle);
grandChild_Child_ParentHandles.remove(childParentHandles);  //remove parent,child window handle from set

//Now switch the control to grand_Child window
driver.switchTo().window((String) grandChild_Child_ParentHandles.toArray()[0]);
```

Comment: Hi, this does'nt seem to work. driver.switchTo().window((String) childParentHandles.toArray()[0]);  always points to the main  window. I had to use toArray()[1] for child window and grandchild is  still not recognised

Comment: Before using this driver.switchTo().window((String) childParentHandles.toArray()[0]); I've remove main window handle from the set using childParentHandles.remove(mainWindowHanhle);. So It will return child window handle only.